# Why EntityFramework.Extended library don't need to call SaveChanges() when Update and Delete?

Tags: entity-framework, design-patterns, ado.net

I am looking at [EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended) . It can run Update() and Delete() on the db entities. like:

```
//delete all users where FirstName matches
context.Users.Delete(u => u.FirstName == "firstname");
```

But the funny thing is, it don't need to call `context.SaveChanges()`, it just go directly into the DB and delete the records.

Is it a bad design? I think every modification on entities will need to call `SaveChanges()` to take effect and keep the correct relationships and mappings between database and memory objects.

Comment: As you may know it's an open source library, check its source code to recognize why ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to understand what SaveChanges does.  SaveChanges commits object model changes that are stored in the current Local cache.

The library you are referring to generates SQL command statements, and do not modify the object context.  As such, since the object context is not altered, there are no changes to save (in other words, SaveChanges refers to the data model, not the database).

To illustrate this... Imagine the difference between your kids taking the bus to school, and you dropping them off.

When they take the bus to school, the school bus drives around to its various stops, and then when it's finished the bus drops all the kids off at once.  This is sort of like calling SaveChanges.

But when you take you drop your kids off at school, it's a single task that gets done in a single action, at the time you do it.

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in the in the Readme. https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended. If you know what you want to delete and you need to delete multiple entities it is faster just to go to database and delete these instead of bringing them to the context just to delete these. It is like executing a SQL command with ExecuteSqlCommand but you don't see the SQL here. On the other hand if your context is tracking entities you are deleting/updating you will most likely end up seeing some exceptions so you need to know what you are doing, why you are doing it and when you are doing this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, tracking entities is what i just worried about. I am afraid that once I call Delete(), records got deleted in DB, but EF don't know it been deleted so it will still keep wrong entities in the memory.